# Simple background color css jquery switching loop

Tags: php, html, css

I was working in HTML and had a div, and within that div, I had an ID and a Class named seventy for example with some attributes.  This is simplified as to illustrate my question:

```
<?php

    $height = 'seventy';
?>

<div id="meter" class="<? echo $height;?> "></div>
```

This worked perfectly from my laptop running Xampp.  When I run it on server 2003, running Xampp, the div tag closed early, and I got a simple textdisplay of ' "> ' after where the div went.  So after messing around for a while I discovered that '

```
<?php

    $height = 'seventy';
?>

<div id="meter" class="<?php echo $height;?> "></div>
```

It worked.  Can anyone give me some insight as to why sometimes you can shorthand the open tag and sometimes you can not.  I am very novice, and this kind of thing intriges me.

Answer (score 0):

When in `php.ini` the `short_open_tag` is `on` you can use the short version: `<?`

It can be also enabled in `.htaccess`:

```
php_flag short_open_tag on
```

It is always best to make your script with `<?php` for portability.

Answer (score 0):

The servers configuration determines weather you can use the php shorthand or not. Only some servers are configured to support this whilst all servers (with PHP) support the full/long method, which is why it is always recommended/good practice to use that instead.